# Is posting unintellegible code bad?

Tags: discussion

A while ago, I posted a question about [a piece of highly unintellegible code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272422/ulp-comparison-code) that I found flying around the web, trying to understand how (and why) it works.

Judging from the vote balance, people didn't like my question.

I have a hard time understanding what it is about my question that sparked the displeasure:

- Is it considered "off-topic" to post unintellegible code asking for explanations?
- Do people feel that my question does not exhibit enough personal research effort?
- Is it just that people instinctivily downvote questions that have "bad code" inside?
- Or is it something else entirely that I didn't think of yet?

Comment: I think it should be OK as long as you demonstrate an attempt to understand how the code works.

Comment: That's pretty mild voting for a question about UB, strictly taboo in [c++] land.  Just read the IEEE-754 spec if you want to understand what it does.

Comment: It's till strange to me that simply asking about a piece of bad code triggers downvotes - I would like to think that it would generate upvotes to see that the OP clearly sees there's something fishy going on, and just can't pin down where it is. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Its hard to speak after the fact, but I'd probably not upvote the question for being of very little practical use. Its more of a matter of curiosity, you're not really solving a problem here unless you happen to run into the same kind of abuse in code you have to maintain - but that doesn't make this question any easier to find. But I wouldn't downvote, because I did learn something.